# In digital physics, how would additional information such as velocity be encoded into bits?

Tags: information

Assuming that at the bedrock of reality, there is some unary particle from which everything is derived, such that there either is a unary particle in some space or there isn't, how would information such as velocity be encoded?

Comment: This is off-topic unfortunately, as it's not a question about mainstream physics.

Comment: @tfb what forum should I put it on, then?

Comment: I don't know, sorry!  I only really participate in the physics SE among the science ones.

Comment: take a look at the idea of glider guns in life https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_(cellular_automaton) ... one idea is that particles are like 3d gliders. velocity (eg of a glider) is not exactly encoded into the system directly, its an emergent property of the CA update rules. nobel winner 't Hooft + other leaders such as Susskind advocate CAs/ digital physics ideas. more discussion try chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9446/theory-salon https://vzn1.wordpress.com/2017/03/31/universe-as-a-simulation-hypothesis-holographic-principle-recent-developments-notes-minisurvey/